# Firebase not reading, is there any way to fix this?

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

It seems that I cannot read db.reference('credentials/login/' + logged_username) because when i print it it gives me this error : <firebase_admin.db.Reference object at 0x103a7d190>.

here is my code :

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate('ServKey.json')

logged = input("are you logged in (True / False)")

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://chatat-73f4a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/'
})

ref = db.reference('credentials/')

if logged == "False" :
    register_username = input("What do you want your username to be ? ")
    register_password = input("What do you want your password to be ? ")

login_ref = ref.child('login')
def setlogin() : 
    login_ref.set({
    register_username : {
    'Password' : register_password,     
    }
    })

if logged == "False":    
    setlogin()
    print("ouisir")
      
if logged == "True" :
    logged_username = input("What is your username ? ")
    logged_password = input("What is your password ? ")
    check_password = db.reference('credentials/login/' + logged_username)
    
if check_password == logged_password :
        logged_in = True

print(check_password)
```

I was expecting check_password to be equal to the password of the "logged username" username

Answer (score 1):

`<firebase_admin.db.Reference object at 0x103a7d190>` is not an error, it's actually the print of an object without a string representation. What that is stating is that there's a [`firebase_admin.db.Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#reference) object at the memory address `0x103a7d190`.

Try printing with:

```
print(check_password.get())
```